# Is there a good control panel add-on that provides more robust member search functionality?

Tags: members, search, member-details

We have a client's site that has a handful of custom member profile fields, one of them being used for a street address. This particular client would like to perform a keyword search on that address but there's no way to do that from EE. I know we can build a custom search form on the front-end using Solspace User but I was hoping for a control panel add-on that would provide similar functionality.

Comment: Please select an answer or give more info as to why none of the answers work for you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's nothing native or by way of an addon that provides a better search facility for custom member fields from the control panel. If you specifically wanted this then I'd go with either [Profile:Edit](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/profileedit) or [Zoo Visitor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor) which brings your Member data into regular channels for searching, filtering, and sorting via the Edit screen. They make it much easier when dealing with front-end templates and custom member fields too.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any addons that offer keyword search of member data.

I'd suggest building this in a normal EE template with jQuery. Protect the page with a conditional to only allow access to the member groups you want to view it and create a quick link to the page from inside the EE control panel.

Set up an EE template to pull all the member data into a table using EE tags or the query module and use a jQuery plugin for the search/filtering... [**DataTables**](http://www.datatables.net/) is a free jQuery plugin that will allow searching/filtering and pagination.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success using a standard `GET` form and inserting the search term with PHP into a `{exp:query}` tag on the results template. I then pass the resulting member IDs to [Freemember](https://exp-resso.com/freemember) and output the member data with it. You'll need to have access to your SQL database to identify the ID names of your custom member fields.

**NB: I don't know whether this method is at risk for SQL injection.**

The search form is straightforward:

```
<form method="get" action="/search">
    <label for="s">Search by Member Screen Name, Affiliation, or Maiden Name</label> <br />
    <input type="search" name="s" id="s" /> <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Now for the search results template. Suppose you've created two custom member fields called Member Affiliation and Member Maiden Name, and you want a single search form that returns matches to those two fields as well as Screen Name. Open up `exp_member_fields` in PHPmyAdmin or [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com), look for those fields, and note the `m_field_id` associated with them. Suppose you see they have IDs `10` and `11`.

Now create a search results template (`search/index`). Set *Allow PHP* to `Yes` and *PHP Parsing Stage* to **Input**. Note that Input parsing is less common then Output and it can cause problems if you're using PHP in other ways on the same template.

```
<?php 
    // retrieve input, if any
    $s =isset($_GET["s"]) ? $_GET["s"] : null;
    ?>

    <h2>Search Results for <em><?php echo $s; ?></em>.</h2>

    {!-- 
    Let's search these fields:
    screen_name:        screen_name (it's already part of exp_members)
    member_affil:       m_field_id_10 
    member_maiden:      m_field_id_11
     --}

    {exp:query limit="100" sql="
       SELECT * FROM exp_member_data 
       JOIN exp_members ON exp_members.member_id = exp_member_data.member_id
       WHERE  (
            screen_name LIKE '%<?php echo $s;?>%')
            OR (m_field_id_10 LIKE '%<?php echo $s;?>%')
            OR (m_field_id_11 LIKE '%<?php echo $s;?>%')
            )
            ORDER BY screen_name
            "}

                {embed="search/_member" the_member_id="{member_id}"}

             {/exp:query}
```

Finally, the embedded template (`search/_member`) looks like this:

```
    {exp:freemember:members member_id="{embed:the_member_id}"}
        <h2>{screen_name}</h2>
        Member Affiliation: {member_affil}
        Member Maiden Name: {member_maiden}

        etc...

    {/exp:freemember:members}
```