# Search member custom fields from control panel

Tags: members, control-panel, search

Is there a way to search custom member fields from the control panel? This question was asked in April 13 ([Is there a good control panel add-on that provides more robust member search functionality?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/is-there-a-good-control-panel-add-on-that-provides-more-robust-member-search-fun)) but I'm hoping something's changed since then!

If there's no way to do it, how complex would a module would it be to build? I wouldn't be building myself – just want an idea of how feasible outsourcing something like this would be...